# typescript: declare type of map-like object

Tags: javascript, typescript, serialization

I'm using an object to store a map, keys are strings, values have a fixed type T.

When looking up a key in the object, the type inference assigns it the type T.
But it might be undefined.
In the following example, I would expect entry to have the type `number|undefined`. But typescript infers the type `number`. That doesn't seem correct:

```
const data: {[index:string]: number} = {
    "aa34da": 1,
    "basd23": 2,
    "as34sf": 5
};

const entry = data["doesn't exist"];
console.log(entry);
```

Is this a bug in the type inference?

I am aware of the ES6 Map, which offers a `get()` method of exactly the signature that I would expect. But Map doesn't play well with JSON serialization. I would prefer to just use objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already figured out, there's no bug in type inference because the `data`'s type is explicitly set to "object containing number at any string key". So we should let typescript know that value might be `undefined`:

```
declare const data: { [index: string]: number|undefined };
```

---

You could also use [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) utility to define such a type:

```
declare const data: Record<string, number | undefined>;
```

> `Record<K, T>` Constructs a type with a set of properties K of type T.

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around with the code, I think the proper way to declare a map-like object, where some keys might not point to values is:

```
const data: {[index:string]: number|undefined} = {
    "aa34da": 1,
    "basd23": 2,
    "as34sf": 5
}

const entry = data["doesn't exist"];
```

Comment: Or using Record util: `Record<string, number | undefined>`

Comment: oh this is neat. If you convert the comment to an answer, I'll accept it.